# MySQL SELECT MIN row of INNER JOINed table

Tags: mysql, inner-join

This is what I have currently (cut down a little):

```
SELECT *, item_prices.price AS minPrice
    FROM items  
    LEFT JOIN item_details USING(item_id) 
    LEFT JOIN item_prices USING(item_id) 
WHERE 1=1
GROUP BY item_id;
```

My issue is that `item_prices` may match more than one row for each item - I only want to get the row with the minimum value of `price`. I've been looking around SO and the web for similar questions but I'm feeling a bit out of my depth here, can anyone help?

Comment: `SELECT *, MIN( item_prices.price)` doesn't work?

Comment: I'm an idiot. Please put that in an answer and I'll accept

Comment: thanks everyone, good suggestions but all I needed to do was as @Vyktor suggested. This is what happens when you build yourself a box to think inside and then forget it's there :(

Comment: @jammypeach : Still you have not accepted Vyktor answer.. :D

Comment: @FahimParkar there's a 10 minute (I think...) timeout on new questions before you may accept an answer

Comment: NO, you can accept any time... NO FIGHT...

Comment: nevertheless, it wouldn't let me accept the answer until now. got an orange box saying 'you can accept an answer after 6 minutes' or similar when i tried to accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use query:

```sql
SELECT *, MIN(item_prices.price) AS minPrice
    FROM items  
    LEFT JOIN item_details USING(item_id) 
    LEFT JOIN item_prices USING(item_id) 
WHERE 1=1
GROUP BY item_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace your join to item_prices with a join to a subquery which gets the minimum price for each item:

`left join (select item_id, min(price) price group by item_id) minprice using (item_id)`

I don't usually use MySQL, but I believe that syntax is valid. It might need tweaking.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with a subquery, along the lines of:

```
SELECT *, 
    (SELECT 
        MIN(item_price) 
     FROM 
        item_prices inner 
     WHERE inner.item_id = items.item_id) AS minPrice 
FROM items

GROUP BY item_id;
```